How to determine whether a type is a class instance or object literal
Given that tsserver has no problem showing the difference between objects and classes (you never see an object literal used to represent a class in hover popups), how do I ask it whether some type is an object literal or a class instance?
In the code below, what would I use for IsClass?
type t1 = {
  map: Map<any, any>
  set: Set<any>
  array: any[],
  obj: { test: true }
};
type t2 = {
  { [K in keyof t1]: IsClass<t1[K]> ? "yes" : "no",
  // map: "yes",
  // set: "yes",
  // array: "yes", (probably)
  // obj: "no",
};



There's no difference between class instances and objects in TS (or JS for that matter; { a: 123 } instanceof Object is true, so it's not even like object literals are special "non-class-instance objects". It's just a way to initialize an object.) In TS an anonymous object type and a class instance type and an interface are effectively the same due to structural typing. In some sense you're talking about a distinction without a difference. What is the actual use case where this matters? You might want to [edit] to clarify (unless you just want "nope, sorry" as an answer).
